# Can I set a specific price for the subscription price in the app store?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

When creating a subscription, I select a price for it, but I can only select, I cannot say exactly how much my subscription will be. Example, I selected a value of $ 2.99, but I wanted it to be $ 2.70 and that value does not exist in the list of values.

Is there a way to say what the value is specifically for my subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible. You can only use the `Tiers` that Apple provide.